# Lightning network (lnd): What's the best way to report lnd server issues/ask for help with channels that won't close?

Tags: bitcoind, lightning-network-daemon

I've been running a lnd/bitcoind node (mainnet) for a few months now. I had a couple open channels, made a couple purchases, things seemed pretty stable. But then I moved cross country, and in the process backed up my server and restored my drives to a new machine with a different IP (I might have lost about 3-4 days worth of data in the process). But now neither of my channels seem willing to close (they've been stuck with a decently sized limbo balance in the 'waiting_close_channels' state for like two weeks now).

How do I properly report an issue? What site should I use? What log files need to be available? What other information should I provide?

Thanks!